# How to create a drag-and-drop Bootstrap interface builder?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, drag-and-drop, interface-builder

I am currently trying to create a visual editor that can be used to create a Bootstrap compatible (or simply HTML) interface builder. The goal is to create an application similar to [layoutit](http://www.layoutit.com) or [jetstrap](http://www.jetstrap.com).

In your experience, what is the best approach to do so?

Which technologies are best suited for this kind of applications?

Are there any Javascript/JQuery libraries to help through the creation process?

Any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: https://jqueryui.com/sortable

Comment: @AlexColoma I'm looking for something much more powerful and feature-rich.

Comment: @ferenan :- Did you get such tool or technology that help us build that.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this?

Comment: @ferenan I am also interested in if you found a solution to this.